# Return a large video file to client (Firebase Cloud Function)

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

On a request, I create a large (~30MB) video file (held in /tmp folder) and need to return it to the user, I am just wondering how I return that file to the client/user.
What methods I can use?

I tried directly with the raw data (base64) but there is a 10MB response limit. I've also tried uploading the file to firebase storage, but that comes with a price, wondering if any other cheaper or free ways

Comment: The Cloud Functions don't charge for storage because they don't have permanent persistent storage right (but only a tmp directory)? How many files do you have anyways? Firebase storage has a generous free tier.

Comment: @Dharmaraj This is after around 10 days of using firebase storage, It's the bandwidth of people downloading the file that causes the price (its not that high, but could increase a lot more over time). I delete the file from the /tmp folder after I upload it to firebase storage. https://prnt.sc/zP0ZTEPpGp_1
I haven't been charged for the bytes stored yet.

If this is the only way then that is fine, just wondering if like a free way or just a way to directly send the file instead of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to return file as stream.

Something like `const fileStream = fs.createReadStream('/tmp/file')` to create reading stream and pipe to response like `fileStream.pipe(res)` (if `res` your Express response object).

Comment: Thanks so much! It didn't work at first, but when I switched `res` and `fileStream` it did! 
```js

const fileStream = createReadStream(file);
fileStream.pipe(res);
```

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Changed to `fileStream.pipe(res)` in comment.